# Не стартует сервер

Tags: железо, диск, процессор

Есть платформа TS300-E8-PS4 ASUSTeK с матерью P9D-E Series и с процом  E3-1241 v3.

Вставляю в PCIE INTEL SSD DC P4500 SERIES SSDPE2KX010T1 - не стартует.

4 бипа и тишина.

Устанавливал через простой переходник без активных элементов.

Поддержка NMME определяется процессором? Запустится ли оно через ретаймер? Может обновить прошивку материской платы?

Биос прошил- без результатов.

Comment: @nikialeksey кажется нет другого сервиса где можно задать вопрос по железу

Comment: он английский немножко

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - извините, вопрос по адресу :) удалил свои комментарии по некорректности вопроса